# Hiberate delete rows from table with limit

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi want to delete the millions of rows from the table in batch to avoid locking. I am trying below code but its deleting all the rows.

```
 Session session;
    try {
        session = dao.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        session = dao.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    String sql = "delete from "+clazz.getSimpleName();
    session.createQuery(sql).setFetchSize(limit).executeUpdate();
    dao.getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

Is there any better way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

I am considering "clazz.getSimpleName();" is returning a table name.

If this is the case than your query is -  "delete from 'tablename'" here you are not specifying any condition which restrict the delete statement, that's why it is deleting all the rows from the table.

As you are using setFetchSize - setFetchSize(int value) is a 'hint' to the driver, telling it how many rows it should fetch.

I think this method is not require in case of delete query.

Comment: Yeah i tried "delete from tablename limit 100" but gives me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:280)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)

Comment: try to avoid setFetchsize(limit). This method is used to tell how many rows you want to fetch but in your case you are trying to delete the rows not fetching it.

Comment: Thanks Moni I removed that part but is there any ways I can specify the number of rows to be deleted ?

Comment: why don't you use truncate command since you're deleting without where clause, are you inserting it simultaneously, can you describe the complete use case, if you can't use truncate then put where clause and use top with that

Comment: I think for that you have to specify some condition in where clause or you can use top of that - for example - delete top(n) from tablename  where 'some condition'